# WHATS WRONG IN FOLLOWING CODE,

Tags: plsqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  TRIGGER T12
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON EMP
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
OP VARCHAR2(20);
NEW NUMBER(5);
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
OP := 'INSERT';


ELSIF UPDATING THEN
OP :='UPDATE';
ELSE
OP :='DELETE';
END IF;
INSERT INTO EMP_AUDIT
VALUES(:NEW.EMPNO,:NEW.ENAME,:NEW.SAL,:OLD.EMPNO,:OLD.ENAME,:OLD.SAL);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'TRIGGER T12 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON EMP FOR EACH ROW DECLARE O'

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE TRIGGER T12
AFTER
 INSERT
OR
 UPDATE
OR DELETE ON EMP FOR EACH ROW DECLARE OP VARCHAR2(20);NEW 
NUMBER(5);BEGIN IF INSERTING THEN OP: = 'INSERT';ELSIF UPDATING THEN 
OP: 
  = 'UPDATE';ELSE OP: = 'DELETE';END IF;
INSERT INTO
 EMP_AUDIT
VALUES(
 :NEW.EMPNO,
 :NEW.ENAME,
 :NEW.SAL,
 :OLD.EMPNO,
 :OLD.ENAME,
 :OLD.SAL
     );END;
```

Please check the **TRIGGER T12**